# value is changing before save- angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

i've created an application in angular js, in which i'm getting a json from a factory, upon which it is taken in two controllers **Ctrl1** and **Ctrl2**. The code is working fine but in the structure i've cancel and save button in which when i cancel i need to redo the previous saved changes and when i click save it should update the json.

But since angular is two way binding, the value is getting change even before clicking the save button

My code is as given below

**html**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <form>
            <br></br>{{user}}</form>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" /><br>
        <input type="button" ng-click="save()" value="Save" />
        <input type="button" ng-click="cancel()" value="Cancel" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory('InitApp', function () {
    return {
        name: 'Manu',
        age: 15
    };
});
app.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, InitApp) {
    $scope.user = InitApp;
});

app.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope, InitApp) {
    $scope.user = InitApp;
    $scope.save = function () {

    }
    $scope.cancel = function () {}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that the changing value before hitting save is not desired.  What you want to do  is copy the object in your controller and manipulate/save the copy.

```
app.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, InitApp) {
    $scope.user = angular.copy(InitApp);
});
```

This disconnects the controller object from the service object, leaving you with one source of truth in the service.  Cancel can just rebind to the service object.

Also, in your fiddle you are returning properties and manipulating the service in your controller.  You need to return an object instead so you are not manipulating the service directly and breaking it.

http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/8btk5/45/

Comment: From how I understand your question, it is working properly.  The textbox isn't bound anymore so the text from the other controller isn't being updated.  What isn't working?

Comment: Thats because your save function in the fiddle is empty.  You can set the service object to your modified copy in there.

Comment: Also, in your service, you should restructure it so your not returning properties, but a user object with properties.

Comment: you have declared and defined `$scope.userName` instead of `$scope.user` since i need even `ng-model="user.name"` not `ng-model="userName"` and also need `$scope.user` instead of `$scope.userName`

Comment: Right, that's why I said you need to change your model a bit to return an object instead of the direct service with properties.  Manipulating the service object breaks the service object.  I assumed I answered the question well enough for you to understand what I was meaning and take it from there.

Comment: Updated answer with fiddle.  Here is a video from egghead.io that explains why you don't want to manipulate properties on the scope.  Services are the same thing [link](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot)

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in having like a roll back to the original values in case the user clicks on a `Cancel` button, you should have a copy of the model retrieved from the service, and bind to the copy.

If the user clicks `Cancel` you should discard this copy and reinitialize all values with the original object. Saving the object will require to update the model accordingly and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure I follow your question, but maybe this helps...

The model binding in Angular is only saving the value to your controller and not to your factory.

If you are hoping to update the values in your factory, you'll want to do that within the save method (by calling methods internal to the factory service).